# Janrain (or others?) integration with existing ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on

I have an exiting ASP.NET website that already has user accounts in it. I would now like to simplify logon and considering the use of Janrain. Is this a recommended product? Any alternatives you have used? What do I do with my existing users (I assume I need to extend my membership db to select between them and Janrain tokens)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider [gigya](http://www.gigya.com/) as an alternative, but I don't know its quality.  I am using Janrain Engage currently.  I like Janrain, and have had only one problem that I think relates directly to Janrain: when signing in with OpenID, if the user chooses to view your "privacy policy," an infinite loop occurs on a Janrain page...interrupting the login sequence.

However, it is working for me just fine for sign-ins of Google, Windows Live ID, Facebook, and OpenID (barring the "view privacy policy" on OpenID).

I imagine you should treat your existing users the same way you treat the users that come from delegated authentication.  That is, once a 3rd party has verified the user/password - you will be given info such as the user name, their e-mail address, their web site (if any) among other things.  Put that information into the same database you are currently storing the other user information into.  Now you can treat everyone the same - except that you will not be storing the passwords for some of your users.

What I've described certainly reflects the way it behaves in Wordpress.  Check my [software engineering professional](http://www.ariasamp.net) site as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Jennifer, we use Gigya and it's an terrific product.

They have a feature called "accounting linking" that's probably right up your alley. Your users will be able to link their existing accounts with social network and OpenID identities. The account linking process is pretty well documented:

http://bit.ly/i1gL3H

Hope that helps.

Comment: Be sure to check the cost as well.  Gigya is quite a bit more expensive than JanRain.